# gvim Windows CTRL-O remapped?

Tags: vim

I'm using gvim 7.4 on Windows, and I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> from insert mode quite often (execute one command from normal mode, then come back to insert mode). Something has remapped it (or not) to where it goes home or something from insert mode.

`:imap`, `:nmap`, and `:vmap` don't show any remapping for `CTRL-O`, and I've disabled the call to `mswin.vim` and `behave mswin` from `_vimrc`, but it's still happening.

Has anybody seen this or know how to correct it? Is there some other way to see what mapped it and/or override the mapping?

Comment: `:verbose map <C-o>` to see what maps it. `:verbose imap <C-o>` specifically for insert mode. `vim -u NONE` to read no start-up files or plugins, so you can check your vanilla Vim is fine, if by any chance `:verbose` doesn't find it.

Comment: Sadly, none of those turn anything up. Starting with vim -u NONE, Ctrl-O still goes Home, but there seems to be no mapping for Ctrl-O.

Answer (score 1):

Not really satisfied with this solution, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> behaves in insert mode the way I expect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to behave.

Answer (score 0):

If `:verbose imap <C-o>` doesn't show anything, it could also be caused by event handlers triggered by `InsertLeave` (or `InsertEnter`). You can quickly check via `:set eventignore=all`; if that fixes the problem, you need to go to all handlers listed by `:autocmd InsertLeave` to find the culprit.

Comment: Sadly, none of those turn anything up. Starting with vim -u NONE, Ctrl-O still goes Home, but there seems to be no mapping for Ctrl-O.